# PHP: Is there any difference between timezones which have same value?

Tags: php, time, timezone, unix-timestamp

For example, London and Lisbon and Dublin all share the same time:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s P');// Wed, 30 Dec 2015 13:30:51 +00:00

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s P');// Wed, 30 Dec 2015 13:30:51 +00:00

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s P');// Wed, 30 Dec 2015 13:30:51 +00:00
```

If the timing is the same, is there any hidden differences between such time zones? Like: daylight, any special calculation, any specific functions will give different results, etc. Or it will be exactly the same regardless?

I'm asking this because, for example, in Bahrain `'Asia/Bahrain'` it's +03:00 while in Qatar `'Asia/Qatar'` it's also +03:00, so does it really make difference if I set it to Bahrain or Qatar?

Comment: Places that recognize daylight savings time would be the only major difference, but truly the offset from GMT is the only thing recognized.  I'm not sure why else it would matter, if it works, it works.

Comment: Given that DST changes the offset from GMT *at different dates/ times* there is a significant difference. The exact date/time of the change varies by jurisdiction which is *represented* by the timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are many differences between the various time zones.  PHP uses the IANA/Olson time zone database, also known simply as TZDB.  You can read more about the tz database:

- [On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)
- [At IANA where it is hosted](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)
- [In the description file in tzdb itself](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html)
- [In the tzdb GitHub repository](https://github.com/eggert/tz)

In particular, you can see that each zone has a unique *history*.  While some values may be identical today, they may have diverged in the past, either in offset from UTC, in dates of transitions from one offset to the next (for DST and other reasons), and for abbreviations used over each period.

As an example, here are links to the entries in the tzdb for the zones you asked about.  You will see they are quite different from each other, historically.

- [Europe/London](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2015g/europe#L467-L472)
- [Europe/Dublin](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2015g/europe#L477-L490)
- [Europe/Lisbon](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2015g/europe#L2087-L2095)

Answer (score -2):

No...
They are the same...

PHP uses timezones to calculate the diference in dates and times.